# (keyError: 'CELERY_BROKER_URL')

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

```
File "C:\Users\User\path\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 277, in get_value
raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the CELERY_BROKER_URL environment variable
```

I'm getting this error when I execute the `python manage.py` command.

I already installed `cookiecutter` with its requirements but I don't know where to go from there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create user project with `cookiecutter`, you must set every required settings. In this case, it is `celery`.

[What is celery](https://github.com/celery/celery#whats-a-task-queue)?

If you don't want to use celery, I recommend you to recreate your project. Then type `n` when `cookiecutter` ask to use celery.

If you want to use celery, see this tutorial [First step with Django](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

I give you some advise. `cookiecutter` is powerful tool to create project simply. But if you are not familiar with django and other libraries, the `cookiecutter` could confuse you. So I recommend you not to use the `cookiecutter`. Instead, look at [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) and proceed step by step.

Comment: This link (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) goes nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not a good idea to abandon a technology when you find small issues on initialization,
I started a project with "Cookiecutter Django" and I find It very powerful,
so for those who still have this issue do the following:

Following the cookiecutter documentation https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally.html you will find this:

$ export CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:6379/0

To convert the above command in Windows just follow this post
https://linuxhint.com/windows-equivalent-export-command/

The “setx” command can be utilized in Windows Command Prompt to set environment variables permanently. However, in order to set environment variables just for a session or temporarily, utilize the “set” command.

To set environment variables just for a session or temporarily use:

> set CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:6379/0

To set environment variables permanently use:

> set CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:6379/0